# discord.py bot not replying

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a discord bot, but it is not responding at all. The bot is hosted on repl.it.

My Code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$buy'):
       await message.channel.send('What would you like to buy' + message.author)
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the event decorator to your event listener, in your case that is `@client.event`. The same one you had in your `on_ready` listener.

Also another thing is that you need to convert the message.author to a string to get their full discord tag.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$buy'):
       await message.channel.send('What would you like to buy ' + str(message.author))
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=event#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event

Comment: my bot also goes offline very often how to reduce that thing?

Comment: Thats an issue with repl.it and unfortunately I have no experience with hosting bots there.

Answer (score -2):

You should use :

```py
from discord .ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

The error is in your `on_message` event as it takes command as a normal message to fix this you just need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the `on_message` event.

And then you should use `@client.command()` because it's a better option then `on_message` one because on_message command making process is now old and not that useful you should use `@client.command()`.

Comment: First of all OP's using `discord.Client`, not `commands.Bot`, secondly he didn't define `bot`. *Why* is `@bot.command` better? What are the advantages & downsides?

Comment: Thx for ur suggestion , I have updated answer